# How can I change an HTML class for a mobile device?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I update the Bootstrap class `.row-eq-height` to have `display: block;` for mobile only?

This is what I've tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $( ".row-eq-height" ).css( "display", "block" );
    }
});
```

Comment: no need to use javascript for this, use css media query

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6370690/4639281

Answer (score 2):

CSS method:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .row-eq-height {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Be sure to change the pixel value to target your specific mobile devices.

Read more about media queries here: [CSS Media Queries - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

---

jQuery/JS method:

```
function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
        //Do this
    } else {
        //Do that
    }
}
```

The above code does not support IE9 because of the use of `window.matchMedia()`.

Read more about this method here: [Window.matchMedia() - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia).